# Nginx Round Robin is balancing every second request

Tags: nginx

I have configured nginx to do basic Round Robin load balancing between upstream servers.
The traffic is being distributed evenly between upstream server, I am expecting load to be balanced after every request but instead it is balanced every second request (the load balancer is serving the first 2 HTTP requests to the first server, the following 2 HTTP requests got to the second server etc. ). I have also tried to use weighted load balancing with even weights on upstream servers and behavior stays the same.

load balancer config:

```
######################  Upstream directive   ######################
upstream backend {
   server ecslb.bknd-srv-one.com:10000;
   server ecslb.bknd-srv-two.com:10000;
   server ecslb.bknd-srv-three.com:10000;
}

######################  Server directive   ######################
server {
   listen 10000;   
   server_name research-complex.com;
   location / {
   proxy_pass http://backend;
   }
}
```

The load-balancer config is loaded by nginx.conf which was left default, only a resolver was added.
Any thoughts what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Looks like your are not the only one with this problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257595/nginx-round-robin-load-balancing-is-not-as-expected

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

*Not sure if this is your exact case, but it may help others who come here.*

The documentation for the `server` directive says that

> A domain name that resolves to several IP addresses defines multiple servers at once.
> http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server

So if the address specified in `server` is resolved into multiple IP addresses, Nginx will also create multiple upstream servers and balance between them. It may then look as if Nginx is passing two requests in a row to the same upstream server, but it's actually two "different" upstream servers (with different IP addresses).

In my case, I was using `localhost` as the server address, which, according to my */etc/hosts* file, resolves to both `127.0.0.1` and `::1` IP addresses. For example:

```
# /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
...

::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
...
```

Then, in a configuration like:

```
upstream backend {
   server localhost:8001;
   server localhost:8002;
}
```

Nginx would balance between 4 servers - `127.0.0.1:8001`, `[::1]:8001`, `127.0.0.1:8002` and `[::1]:8002`.