# How to add NGINX upstream to a serverpilot install?

Tags: nginx

I want to load balance a Serverpilot install between 2 servers. The config doesn't seem to use any 'upstream' so I'm confused about how to add it. This is what i have:

**/etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/server1.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name
        sv1.domain.com
      ;

    root   /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/server1/public;

    access_log  /srv/users/serverpilot/log/server1/server1_nginx.access.log  main;
    error_log  /srv/users/serverpilot/log/server1/server1_nginx.error.log;

    proxy_set_header    Host              $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    include /etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/server1.d/*.nonssl_conf;
    include /etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/server1.d/*.conf;
}
```

**/etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/server1.d/main.conf**

```
location / {
    proxy_pass      $backend_protocol://$backend_host:$backend_port;
}
```

I want to add the current server IP and a new IP to an upstream so Nginx round robin between the 2 instead of using the sole server. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx round-robin nor exactly round-robin](https://serverfault.com/questions/895116/nginx-round-robin-nor-exactly-round-robin)

Comment: Should i simply add the upstream above the server and change main.conf proxy_pass to point to that upstream?

Comment: @geraldschneider please provide the full answer ,it solves the question ;)

Comment: @djdomi I casted a close vote, the comment is added automatically. When others confirm the vote the question will be closed as a duplicate. There is no need to add the same answer again.

Comment: your right ,i did the same